# fork() not working using Cygwin

Tags: c++

Here's my code that I am compliling:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int shared_variable = 100;

int main()
{
int sum = 0;
int n = fork();

if (n > 0) {                    //producer process
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        int val = (rand() % 3) + 1;
        Sleep(val*1000);
        shared_variable = i;
    }

}

else {                          //consumer process
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        int val = (rand() % 3) + 1;
        Sleep(val*1000);
        sum += shared_variable;
    }

    ofstream file;
    file.open ("result.txt");
    file <<"John Smith\n";      //replace your name
    file <<"ICS 462 Assignment #1\n";
    file <<"The sum is " <<sum;
    file.close();
}
return 0;
}
```

When I am compiling the code using Cygwin or Dev C++, I am getting this error saying [fork not declared in scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va9MV.jpg). 
Please tell me what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Of the headers you've included, which do you think provides `fork`?

Comment: What is `fork()`? The posix `fork()`? Unlikely to be supported on Windows. Huh. Cygwin does have `fork` working. Neat-o. All you should need then is the right header.

Comment: @user4581301: Cygwin has a `fork()`, but it ain't your grandaddy's `fork()`. It's insanely slow and more than a little glitchy.

Answer (score 0):

Using Unix-like systems, `fork()` is declared in `<unistd.h>`.

When compiling with g++, you may need to include the file in an `extern "C"` block to prevent mangling like so:

```
extern "C" {
#include <unistd.h>
}
```

Comment: At least in this case, Cygwin is Unix-like enough.  :)

Comment: So i added #include <unistd.h> and I am still getting the same error that fork() is not declared in the scope. I also tried the method given by "jdc" and it also gives the same error message.

Comment: @Yong Her Are you using Cygwin?

Comment: Yes I am using Cygwin to compile.

Comment: @YongHer:  If you have Cygwin installed but are really invoking the mingw g++ compiler, then you will have this problem.  Type `which g++` from the prompt and see which compiler you are using.  Mingw does not have `fork` in unistd.h, but cygwin does.  You can also run `g++ -E myfile.cpp` to see the preprocessor output, which will show you which `unistd.h` your compiler is using, which may give a clue.

Comment: @indiv is right.  The latest version of Cygwin offers installs of many g++ compilers for different toolchains.  I was able to compile a working .cpp file using `fork()` with the `gcc-g++` compiler under Cygwin.

Comment: When I type "which g++" it gives me the following output: /cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin/g++

Comment: @YongHer:  You are running the g++ compiler that is installed with [Strawberry Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl), which according to wikipedia is Mingw.  You need to install cygwin's g++ and use that.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks guys, I went back and install g++-gcc packages from cygwin and it works. Thank you very much!